# Why are some areas of this model dark after AO bake (not dark in render, only in bake)

Tags: texture-baking

I've been pulling my hair out over this. I have downloaded a model from turbosquid, did a "Lightmap Pack" UV unwrap and then baked AO onto it. In the render view, the AO looks fine, but when baked there are large areas of the model that are completely black.

I understand this model could be much better UV-unwrapped but is that the issue here? Or is there something else going on? I don't understand why poor unwrapping would result in what I'm seeing.

Here is a screenshot of an area in render view and then baked. I have also uploaded the blender file itself [here](https://file.io/wnYVAn) (https://file.io/wnYVAn), to see if anyone can see what's wrong... (I'm using Blender 2.80).

[image: Cycles view of AO at problem area]

[image: Baked AO]

Comment: The AO that you're using in the material isn't equivalent to the  AO from the *World* tab.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Are you referring to the "distance" parameter in the AO under the world tab? If so, I just tried changing to that to be 1.0 (to match the material). The issue still occurs, sadly...

Comment: Have you checked how it looks in the viewport with a simple diffuse material and world AO enabled (no AO node)? Is the area inside dark like in the bake?

Comment: I just checked that now and, no, those areas are not black in the viewport (render view with cycles).